# Android Navigation Drawer with sliding TabView

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I stumbled into a crazy little 'bug', or i'm just doing something wrong. I am trying to get the swipe tab view in main activity, swipe tabView perfectly working but the main problem is when click on Navigation Drawer Menu then the fragment are overlaying each other. please Help..

here is my two tabView Fragment

1.NewsFragment

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

public static NewsFragment newInstance(){
    NewsFragment newsFragment=new NewsFragment();
    return newsFragment;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment,null);
}}
```

2.NoticeFragment

```
public class NoticeFragment extends Fragment {
public static NoticeFragment newInstance(){
    NoticeFragment noticeFragment=new NoticeFragment();
    return noticeFragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.notice_fragment, container, false);
}}
```

Here is my two xml for two fragment

1.News_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="News\nFragment"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Android Sikkha"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

2.notice_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Notice\nFragment"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Android Sikkha"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i have another java file called Home which is same as previous one java file  and also xml is same.

Here is the MainActivity

```
package com.example.user.navwithtab;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
 DrawerLayout drawer;
 ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Setear adaptador al viewpager.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    // Preparar las pestañas
    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(NewsFragment.newInstance(), "News");
    adapter.addFragment(NoticeFragment.newInstance(), "Notice");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}





@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.home) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new HomeFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.announcement) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new AnnouncementFragment()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    //DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}}
```

here is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Sorry for long post.

Note: Navigation Drawer and swipe View working perfectly but the problem is on fragment overlay.[after clicking navigationbarmenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvusG.png)

Here is my logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.user.navwithtab, PID: 3400
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.user.navwithtab.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:157)
                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:153)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
                  at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:328)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(..)` in your `onNavigationItemSelected `. Can you post the content of `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: Do not create new `DrawerLayout`

Comment: @adnbsr Where is he doing that?

Comment: @rebenlop88 just posted activity_main.xml.

Comment: @adnbsr I am new in android studio, can u just explain it

Comment: @ShantuDas when does overlay occurs. When you select item from navigation drawer or when swiping tabView

Comment: @7geeky  when i select item from navigation drawer menu

Comment: @ShantuDas check my answer below and see if making this change works;

Answer (score 0):

In `onNavigationItemSelected` method do not create the `DrawerLayout` again. Simply call the `closeDrawer`.

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); --> remove this line of code
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

**UPDATE**

In your onCreate method change this line of code

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

to

```
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

and add this line of code

```
DrawerLayout drawer
```

below this line of code

```
 ViewPager mViewPager;
```

and remove the indicated line of code in `onNavigationItemSelected` method

Comment: if i remove this line, how can i get the drawer object, so that i can invoke closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START) function.

Comment: Did you give it a try? It would work because you've already initialized it

Comment: Yes, i already did, when i remove this line it shows can not resolve drawer

Comment: Oops! That's because you'd have to declare drawer as a field. And it should work

Comment: i am in new in android. how can i create drawer as a field

Comment: I've tried to explain it in the updated answer. Try this and see if it works.

Comment: also tried this, swipe tab is working but when i choose from navigation drawer menu app crashes.

Comment: could you please post the log cat

Comment: added logcat in my question

Comment: and if you may update rest of the changes you made in the code as well;

Comment: just udated the code, only changes are in main activity as you told to do

Comment: please follow the instruction promptly. in onCreate method you didn't remove `DrawerLayout` keyword from the line of code `DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);` Do this and then tell if are sill unable to run it

Comment: also did that, apps running but overlay occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (id == R.id.home) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new HomeFragment()).commit();
} else if (id == R.id.announcement) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new AnnouncementFragment()).commit();
```

update above code as below :

```
if (id == R.id.home) {
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new HomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
} else if (id == R.id.announcement) {
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new AnnouncementFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```